# How to install a service with the currently logged user in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, service

How can I install a service developed in .Net with the currently logged user? In the ServiceInstaller I have the properties UserName and Password but I don't have this information.

Can I somehow say: "just use the currently logged user"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to run as a specific user you *must* supply both username and password.  If you have to prompt the user for them, then do so.

Comment: If I was able to do it ... :S Thanks anyway.